# Adding jar to vscode debug extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

We are having a runnable jar for the DAP(Debugger Adapater Protocol) of ABL language and we are planning to add a vscode extension for that ABL DAP.

Could you provide us some documentation or give us an idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two approaches for making VS Code run your *.jar:

**Declarative**:
In the `package.json` of your extension, you can register your executable as part of the `debuggers` extension point. Here is the doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/debugger-extension#anatomy-of-the-package.json-of-a-debugger-extension. 
And here is an example from the node.js debugger.
Basically the following attributes are available:

```
  "runtime": "node",
  "runtimeArgs": [ "--arguments_passed_to_runtime" ],
  "program": "./dist/dap.js",
  "args": [ "--arguments_passed_to_program" ],
```

The resulting command that VS Code will call is this:

```
  node --arguments_passed_to_runtime ./dist/dap.js --arguments_passed_to_program
```

You do not have to make a distinction between runtime and program. You can use either "runtime" or "program" and leave out the other.

**Non-declarative**:
Alternatively you can use extension code to "calculate" the command that VS Code should execute when launching your Debug Adapter. See this API: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4c3769071459718f89bd48fa3b6e806c83cf3336/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L8797-L8816
Based on this API the following snippet shows how you could create a DebugAdapterDescriptor for your abl debugger:

```js
// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {

  vscode.debug.registerDebugAdapterDescriptorFactory('abl', {
      createDebugAdapterDescriptor(session: DebugSession, executable: DebugAdapterExecutable | undefined): ProviderResult<DebugAdapterDescriptor> {
          return new vscode.DebugAdapterExecutable(
              "/usr/bin/java",
              [
                  join(context.extensionPath, "bin", "abl.jar")
              ],
              {
                  "cwd": "some current working directory path",
                  "env": {
                      "key": "value"
                  }
              }
          );
      }
  });
}
```